CLERK for RBAC for expo react native
I am new to React Native and Expo. I am learning about protected pages but can't get my head through choosing a good RBAC.
I am using Clerk as the main authentication and does someone here know how to implement role-based for the pages of my app? I did read the docs but it is confusing since there are no details about RBAC in Expo React Native.
I wanted to know more about Clerk and wanted to learn more about RBAC using CLERK and implement it to my project.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
